# Only first Compute Shader array element appears updated

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, compute-shader

Trying to send an array of integer to a compute shader, sets an arbitrary value to each integer and then reads back on CPU/HOST. The problem is that only the first element of my array gets updated. My array is initialized with all elements = 5 in the CPU, then I try to sets all the values to 2 in the Compute Shader:

C++ Code:

```
   this->numOfElements = std::vector<int> numOfElements; //num of elements for each voxel

   //Set the reset grid program as current program
    glUseProgram(this->resetGridProgHandle);

    //Binds and fill the buffer 
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, this->counterBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(int) * numOfVoxels, this->numOfElements.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, this->counterBufferHandle);

    //Flag used in the buffer map function
    GLint bufMask = GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT;

    //calc maximum size for workgroups
    //glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, &result);

    //Executes the compute shader
    glDispatchCompute(32, 1, 1); // 
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BARRIER_BIT);

    //Gets a pointer to the returned data
    int* returnArray = (int *)glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);

    //Free the buffer mapping
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
```

Shader:

```
#version 430
layout (local_size_x = 32) in;
layout(binding = 0) buffer SSBO{
    int counter[];
};

void main(){
    counter[gl_WorkGroupID.x * gl_WorkGroupSize.x + gl_LocalInvocationID.x] = 2;
}
```

If I print returnArray[0] it's 2 (correct), but any index > 0 gives me 5, which is the initial value initialized in host.

Answer (score 1):

```
glMemoryBarrier(GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BARRIER_BIT);

//Gets a pointer to the returned data
int* returnArray = (int *)glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
```

The bit you use for [`glMemoryBarrier`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMemoryBarrier) represents the way you *want* to read the data written by the shader. `GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BARRIER_BIT` says "I'm going to read this written data by using the buffer for vertex attribute arrays". In reality, you are going to read the buffer by *mapping* it.

So you should use the proper barrier bit:

```
glMemoryBarrier(GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i had this problem as well
i changed:

```
layout(binding = 0) buffer SSBO{
```

to:

```
layout(binding = 0, std430) buffer SSBO{
```